# Zoom into picture frame

Tags: video, effects

I am not sure how to describe this effect.  but..

I want to show a video with a picture frame in it.  I want the blender camera to zoom in on the picture frame and eventually just be showing the video that was playing in the picture frame.  I am sure this has a name, just not sure what it is.

Comment: you can play a movie into your 3D scene if this is what you're looking for, you just need to give a plane an Image Texture node and load the movie into this node or even simpler, Add Image > Image > Image as Planes (you need to enable the Import Image as Planes addon)

Comment: [Pan & Zoom Slide Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNEERJs1dsk)?